# Uncheck/Check show content jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code

```
<div class="option-other">
                <h5>Color:</h5>
                    <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="50" data-value="Red"> Red <br/>
                    <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="30" data-value="Green"> Green <br/>
                    <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="40" data-value="Blue"> Blue <br/>
                <h5>Layout</h5>
                    <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="50" data-value="1 Column "> 1 Column <br/>
                    <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="60" data-value="2 Column"> 2 Column <br/>
                    <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="70" data-value="3 Columnq"> 3 Column <br/>
            </div>
```

I would when check checkbox show content and uncheckbox hidden content. How to code for Jquery ?
Example : check checkbox "Red" show content "Red" and uncheckbox "Red" hidden content "Red".
Like website https://www.designquote.net/html/dq_estimate_wizard.cfm

Comment: Try this **[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/sDsCM/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for Javascript or jQuery. CSS can do that too, by wrapping the text in a `<span>` and using the [`:checked` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked), in combination with the [`+` adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
.option-other input[type=checkbox]+span {
  display: none;
}
.option-other input[type=checkbox]:checked+span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-other">
  <h5>Color:</h5>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="50" data-value="Red"><span> Red </span><br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="30" data-value="Green"><span> Green </span><br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="40" data-value="Blue"><span> Blue </span><br/>
  <h5>Layout</h5>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="50" data-value="1 Column "><span> 1 Column </span><br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="60" data-value="2 Column"><span> 2 Column </span><br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="70" data-value="3 Columnq"><span> 3 Column </span><br/>
</div>
```

## Based on the link in the comment.

On every change on a input, you want to loop all the checked inputs, combine their data-values, and put that in a separate div...

```js
$(".option-other input").on('change', function() {
  var result = "";
  $('.option-other input:checked').each( function() {
    result += $(this).data('value') + '<br />';
  });
  $('.result').html( result );
});
```

```css
.option-other,
.result {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-other">
  <h5>Color:</h5>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="50" data-value="Red"> Red <br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="30" data-value="Green"> Green <br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="40" data-value="Blue"> Blue <br/>
  <h5>Layout</h5>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="50" data-value="1 Column "> 1 Column <br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="60" data-value="2 Column"> 2 Column <br/>
  <input class="other-select" type="checkbox" data-price="70" data-value="3 Columnq"> 3 Column <br/>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Nifty answer. You are prawn to forget that CSS allows for these tricks :D

Comment: but I want build app like to https://www.designquote.net/html/dq_estimate_wizard.cfm, column left when user click checkbox, and column right show content checkbox that and un-check hidden

Comment: Then you might want to rewrite your question @Jackey.... But I'll see what I can make....

Comment: If the answer suits you, please mark it as solution, by hitting the v-mark on the left of it.